# How can I Re-Enable the Windows 8.1 Start Button?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-explorer, touchscreen

For some reason I'm unable to click or tap (Touchscreen) on the Windows start button in the bottom left. If I use a keyboard, I can bring up the start menu, but not with mouse. If I move the taskbar to any other side of the screen the start button will work. Issue is for this computer the task bar needs to be at the bottom. (For work) I also can't right click on the start menu, but Win X works to open the short cut menu.

Any Ideas on what could be causing this. I can't really resort to re-installing as I'm using an image I was supplied with.

Any registry key that might affect this? I've tried a few with no luck.

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: Yeah, every time I tried changing a setting. Luckily it's on a ssd.

Comment: It sounds like one of your startup programs is messing something up. Check your Accessibility Options to see if something is messed up and edit your startup programs into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have, unfortunately encountered this bug. There is a way to fix it, but it's not so pretty.

1. Right Click on the Task Bar and select Task Manager.
   [image: Right Clicking]
2. Click More Details[image: More Details]
3. Switch to the Details tab[image: Details Tab]
4. Locate `explorer.exe` and end it[image: Kill Explorer]
5. Go to File -> Run and run `explorer`[image]
6. That should fix the error with the tray

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, tried it multiple times. :(
I think someone disabled it as it works in the admin account, but not our standard user account.

Comment: dang. that's what has always worked for me. is it possible that the image you were given was corrupt?

Comment: No, don't think so. Works fine on a computer meant for windows 8, the computer we installed this image over is meant for Windows XP, but shouldn't matter as we have another image with windows 8 that works fine.

Comment: mind adding the HW specs of the XP PC?

Comment: Not sure it'll help, but 1.9ghz dual core, IR touchscreen, 2gb ram, 120gb ssd.

Comment: assuming that neither the image or the hardware is at fault, my suspect would be the drivers

Comment: I don't think it's drivers because we have a slightly different image with windows 8 and the start button works fine, but we can't use it because of some various changes meant for the computers with the image.

Comment: Basically same hardware w/ 2 different similar images.

Comment: from your reasoning, it now looks like the windows install itself is suspect

Comment: could you not use the older image and install whatever is new manually?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have control over it and I don't know all the difference between the 2 images to update it myself. I know there have been changes to disable the charms and app switcher, but how would that affect the start button on just this hardware.

Comment: disabling the charms is quite possibly what has caused the start button to stop working

Comment: Re-enabled everything and didn't do anything... Any other ideas?

Comment: I;m out of ideas. If you get whoever made the image to update it once installed though it should work